# jQuery, Ajax, SQL Pagination, problems with SESSION

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my first time doing pagination with jQuery ajax.
I do it like this:

I include file 'GetAllMessages.php' into a div, only if i'm logged in.[**works]**

I include file 'GetMessages.php' again only if im logged in which tells me how many messages are in database.**[works]**

When I click on my 'messages' link I open a popup and I get my first four messages from 'GetAllMessages.php'.**[works]**

At the end of this div i have pages like [1,2,3...] and then with jquery $.ajax function (post method) i go again into 'GetAllMessages.php' but this time I tell the file which page I clicked so it gives me the messages I want next.**[doesnt work]**

**It's like SESSION does not exsist, but if I add 'SESSION_START' at start in 'GetAllMesasages.php' it says its already started on my initial 'GetAllMessages.php' load, but when I click on page link[1,2,3...] the error goes away and it all works.**

*GetAllMessages.php*

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["uname"])){
include ('config.php');
include ('getMessages.php');

$pages=$messageCount/$messagesPerPage;

if(isset($_POST["page"])){
$page=$_POST["page"];
}else{
$page=1;
}

$startQuery=($page-1)*$messagesPerPage;

$getMessagesQuery = "SELECT * from messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$startQuery.",".$messagesPerPage."";
$result = $conn->query($getMessagesQuery);
if($result->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $mId=$row["id"];
        $mName=$row["name"];
        $mEmail=$row["email"];
        $mMessage=$row["message"];
        $mDate=$row["messageDate"];
        $mIsRead=$row["seen"];
        $mIsAnswered=$row["answered"];

        if($mIsRead==0){
            $messageStatus="unread";
            $markReadButton="<button class='button1'>Mark as read</button>";
        }else if($mIsAnswered==1){
            $markReadButton="";
            $messageStatus="answered";
        }else{
            $markReadButton="";
            $messageStatus="";
        }                       
        echo "
        <div class='message ".$messageStatus."' data-messageid='".$mId."'>
            <p class='date'>".$mDate."</p>
            <p class='sender'>".$mName." - ".$mEmail."</p>
            <p class='messageContent'>".$mMessage."</p>
            <span class='buttons'>              
            <button class='reply'>Reply</button>
            ".$markReadButton."
            </span>
        </div>";
    }
}
}else die();
?>
```

Comment: "if I add 'SESSION_START' at start in 'GetAllMesasages.php' it says its already started on my initial 'GetAllMessages.php' load"  can you please post the exact error?

Comment: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in xxxxxxxx\getAllMessages.php on line 2 @GrafiCodeStudio

Comment: is it possible you have another session_start() in getMessages.php?

Comment: No, I have one in index.php which includes both, getMessages and getAllMessages @GrafiCodeStudio

Comment: if you print_r( $_SESSION ); in index.php, right after session_start(), what's the output? is your uname set?

Comment: Array ( [uname] => troix1 [userStatus] => 2 [name] => myname[surname] => mylastname[email] => myemail ) @GrafiCodeStudio

Comment: it looks fine, one last clarification, where in index.php do you include GetAllMessages.php? I mean, is it at the beginning of the code?

Comment: on the bottom of the document:
<div id="messagesPop" class="popup">
<h1>Messages</h1>
<div id="messages">
 <?php
  if(isset($_SESSION["uname"])){
  include('getAllMessages.php');} ?> 
  </div>
  <?php 
  for($i=0;$i<$pages;$i++){
   echo "<a href='#' class='pageLink' data-page='".($i+1)."'>".($i+1)."</a>";
  } 
  ?> @GrafiCodeStudio

Comment: try using include_once instead of include.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92327/discussion-between-troix-and-graficode-studio).